# How to set Windows Services permissions from Powershell?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, service

I need to grant a specific account [SERVICE_START permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981(VS.85).aspx) for a given Windows service.

There seems to be some methods for doing so [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;288129), but would prefer a method that's native to PowerShell and doesn't require external tools, for ex. by using Get/Set-ACL cmdlets, or calling some .NET API.

Does someone know how to do it in that fashion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this you should look into using `subinacl.exe` which you can [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en).  From the download it site it is described as:

> *SubInACL is a command-line tool that enables administrators to obtain
>   security information about files,
>   registry keys, and services, and
>   transfer this information from user to
>   user, from local or global group to
>   group, and from domain to domain.*

Using it from PowerShell appears to be pretty easy:

```
SUBINACL /verbose=1 /service Spooler /grant=PC\Joe=LQSTOP
```

Check out this [article on using subinacl](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/permissions/edit-permissions-with-subinacl.aspx) that Mark Minasi wrote..

Comment: Thanks Keith. While this is helpful, it's not officially supported by Windows Server 2008 and later, which makes it unelegible in our data center. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Cold question deserves a partial answer.

Check out http://get-carbon.org/

If you don't want to install carbon on a production server then look a the source (Apache 2.0 Licence) and see if you can utilise the .NET code for your own devices. If I had time I would expand this answer to include example code but for now see these two parts of the repository.

Powershell CmdLet
https://bitbucket.org/splatteredbits/carbon/src/29f5983094d048030d6143923f4a6925d1a1a195/Carbon/Service/Grant-ServicePermission.ps1?at=default

Uses a .Net object (using system)
https://bitbucket.org/splatteredbits/carbon/src/29f5983094d048030d6143923f4a6925d1a1a195/Source/Security/ServiceAccessRights.cs?at=default

From that it should be a hop skip and a jump to write your own Powershell v3+ native call.